# Azure Python SDK - Handling multiple data disk attachments for a VM

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

I am trying to iterate through a json file and attach data disks sequentially. However, I found with my current code it appears each of the data disks get attached, then promptly removed to make way for the other one.

```
   def json_parse(self, compute_client):
    """Parses the local .json file for previously attached disks"""
    with open(self.json_path) as fp:
        ingest = json.load(fp)
        for disk in ingest['storageProfile']['dataDisks']:
            result = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
                self.rg_name,
                self.vm_name,
                VirtualMachine(
                    location=ingest['location'],
                    storage_profile=StorageProfile(
                        data_disks=[DataDisk(
                            lun=disk['lun'],
                            caching=disk['caching'].lower(),
                            create_option=DiskCreateOptionTypes.attach,
                            name=disk['name'],
                            vhd=VirtualHardDisk(
                                uri=disk['vhd']['uri']
                                )
                                        )]
                                    )
                                )
                            )
            print('Attaching disk {0} with name {1}, waiting until complete...'.format(disk['lun'], disk['name']))
            result.result()

    print('All disks should be attached now.')
```

For example here is the workflow for 3 data disks in my json file:

1. First data disk gets attached to lun 0
2. First data disk is removed instantly
3. Second data disk is attached to lun 1
4. Second data disk is removed instantly
5. Third data disk is attached to lun 2
6. Third data disk stays as the only disk attached to the VM

Is this because I am using the same variable `result` and when the loop iterates over the next disk it gets overwritten? I have no idea how I would solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with creating a list of `data_disk` objects and passing them all at once to the `create_or_update` call.

```
    def json_parse(self, compute_client):
    """Parses the local .json file for previously attached disks"""
    with open(self.json_path) as fp:
        ingest = json.load(fp)
        dd = []
        for disk in ingest['storageProfile']['dataDisks']:
            a_disk = DataDisk(
                lun=disk['lun'],
                caching=disk['caching'].lower(),
                create_option=DiskCreateOptionTypes.attach,
                name=disk['name'],
                vhd=VirtualHardDisk(
                    uri=disk['vhd']['uri']
                    )
                            )
            dd.append(a_disk)
            #print('Attaching data disk {0} with name {1}, waiting until complete...'.format(dd[0][0].lun, dd[0][0].name))

    result = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
        self.rg_name,
        self.vm_name,
        VirtualMachine(
            location=ingest['location'],
            storage_profile=StorageProfile(
                data_disks=dd
                            )
                        )
                    )
    result.wait()

    print('All disks should be attached now.')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you always send a new list of one element for `data_disks`. You need to get the VM result of your `create_or_update` (from `result.result()`, see [here](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.create_or_update)) and reuse it for the next call, appending your new disk to `data_disks`.
Then don't re-create a VM object, but just:
`vm.storage_profile.data_disks.append(my_new_data_disk)`

[This is similar to how resizing a disk](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/blob/master/example.py#L179).

Comment: thank you for the clear and concise answer. I actually ended up going a different route than what you suggested, as I could not figure out how to async the `vm.storage_profile.data_disks.append()` e.g. `.wait()` call for a list of `data_disk` objects. They would all fire off simultaneously and fail to attach inside my loop.

Instead I opted for just constructing a list of `data_disk` objects to use in one `create_or_update` call.

Comment: That's fine too! Just remember than ARM RestAPI treats list as a whole ,if an element is not there in a call, this is interpreted as "I want to remove it".
By the way, you save some HTTP calls :)